# Open Source Tools for Mobile GIS app development?

Tags: open-source-gis, mobile, geography

I want to create a complete **Map application** with the facilities of edit geometry and attributes of layers. The server and client for the application should be some **open source tools**. The application need to run with **Windows Phone 7, iOS and Android**.

Please give me suggestions on the Open Source Tools selection for my development. As a first step i am planning to start with Windows Phone 7.

Answer (score 5):

You can check [GIS Mobile Comparison](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GIS_Mobile_Comparison) by OSgeo.

> This page is used to describe comparisons between GeoSpatial Mobile
>   applications to help users select suitable applications for their
>   requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Input App](https://inputapp.io/en/) based on QGIS ecosystem, fully open-sourced. Either you can create a custom GIS project in it or alternatively, you can also use the Input-SDK to create a custom mobile application for the further customization of the user interface.

disclaimer: I am one of the app develoeper